# writing large netcdf files without memory issues

Tags: memory, dask, netcdf, python-xarray, chunks

I want to merge multiple netdcf files (with the four dimensions 'time','step','y' and 'x') and write them into an outputfile. I used xarray.open_mfdataset() but when writing the file, I get memory issues (even though I use chunking)

This is my code:

```
ds = xr.open_mfdataset('*.nc', chunks ={'time':1,'step':1,'y':1200, 'x'=1100})

file_name = "outfile.nc"
write_job = ds.to_netcdf(file_name, compute=False)
with ProgressBar():
    print(f"Writing to {file_name}")
    write_job.compute()
```

An array of the defined chunk size easily fits into memory, but
all the memory gradually gets eaten up until it crashes.
So can anyone tell me how to avoid these memory issues?

This is the output of print(ds):

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:       (time: 210528, step: 1, y: 1200, x: 1100)
Coordinates:
  * step          (step) timedelta64[ns] 00:00:00
  * time          (time) datetime64[ns] 2019-01-01 ... 2020-12-31T23:55:00
  * x             (x) float64 -543.5 -542.5 -541.5 -540.5 ... 553.5 554.5 555.5
  * y             (y) float64 -4.809e+03 -4.808e+03 ... -3.611e+03 -3.61e+03
    latitude      (y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1200, 1100), meta=np.ndarray>
    longitude     (y, x) float64 dask.array<chunksize=(1200, 1100), meta=np.ndarray>
    missing_data  (time, step) bool dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1), meta=np.ndarray>
Data variables:
    RV_recalc     (time, step, y, x) float32 dask.array<chunksize=(1, 1, 1200, 1100), meta=np.ndarray>
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of each file? Can you include the result of `print(ds)`?

Comment: I added the print(ds) output to the problem description

Comment: And what are the dimensions of each file you’re reading?

Comment: The files, I'm reading contain the data of one month. So, the time dimension varies between 8353 and 8928, step is 1, y is 1200, and x is 1100.

Comment: The chunksize of `"time": 1` in the output array is definitely problematic. What happens if you rechunk to length 1000 along time right after open_mfdataset?

Comment: With chunkszise of 'time':1000, after some time, I get a memory error:
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.92 GiB for an array with shape (1000, 1, 1200, 1100) and data type float32
(I have 128 GB RAM)

Comment: Can you try chunksize 250? You must have run out of ram between the data held on all workers, scheduler, and local.

Comment: Also with chunksize 250, I get a memory error. And I've also tried chunksize 100, but still get the sam error

Comment: I've updated my dask version and rerun my code, and now (at least until now) I haven't got the memory error. But it's already running for 20 hours and only shows one percent of progress, so I don't know wether this is normal...

Comment: Well it’s a huge job for a localcluster - you’re reading and writing about a TB no? Since you’re just concatenating them you may get better performance with nco. But you may just be suffering from disk bottlenecks?

Comment: yes exactly, all files together are about one TB. I've already tried nco (ncrcat), but it crashed without error message...

Comment: Is this on an external drive? 2000 hours does seem extreme. Now that you have it working I’d play with the chunk dude to see if you can speed things along. I’d expect larger chunks to be helpful here as long as you can still comfortably fit them into memory

Comment: it's on a server. i think the problem is that it just hangs after a while (so depending on the chosen chunk size it shows me progress of 10 percent within a few minutes but then makes no more progress)

Comment: I’d definitely recommend writing to zarr rather than netcdf if your storage throughput is high and supports concurrent writes from your different workers

Comment: when I try writeing the file to zarr, again, I get a memory error ( Unable to allocate 49.92 GiB for an array with shape (8928, 1, 1200, 1100)), where (8928, 1, 1200, 1100) is the size of one input file) even though i used a chunksize of 100 for the first dimension

Comment: try to do some profiling as suggested here: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/729

Comment: I've finally managed to write the file to zarr :)  With chunksize 200, and dask.config.set(scheduler='single-threaded').
Thanks for all your help!